# eth0 not working anymore after trying to set static ip

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

Hi I tried to set up a static ip and have lost the ability to use eth0, I can see that it is there but disabled, tried the edit with the auto eth0 and DHCP but to no avail, been trying all sorts of commands that have been suggested in other posts but getting nowhere. need help to reprogram eth0 from scratch.

Comment: It would be useful to edit your question to include the contents of your `/etc/network/interfaces` file to help diagnose where the problem lies.

Answer (score -1):

I have static IP and it works without any problem.
Check your settings again. Check "Gateway" and "DNS servers"

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, please provide full details on how he should verify and test his settings.  This should be a comment, not really an answer.

Answer (score -1):

[Maybe this can help?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/what-happens-with-dhclient-eth0-517695/)

Hopefully. :)